# To append pandas series using for loop

Tags: pandas

I have three Series and list:

```
df1 = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])
df2 = pd.Series(['e','f','g','h'])
df3 = pd.Series(['i','j','k','l'])


df1
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
df2
0  e
1  f
2  g
3  h

df3
0 i
1 j
3 k
4 l

list = [df1,df2,df3]
```

I want to append series using loop like this:

```
 df1  df2   df3
0 a     e    i
1 b     f    j
2 c     g    k
3 d     h    l
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried like this but failed:

```
for i in dflist:
    tempdata = pd.DataFrame([])
    mstdf = tempdata.append(i, ignore_index= True)
    print(mstdf)


   0  1  2  3
0  a  b  c  d
   0  1  2  3
0  e  f  g  h
   0  1  2  3
0  i  j  k  l
```

I have already referenced pandas.DataFrame.append documentation and I've also looked at some of the stack's questions. But I can not solve this problem.

python - add one row in a pandas.DataFrame - Stack Overflow
python - Appending a list or series to a pandas DataFrame as a row ...
python - How to append rows in a pandas dataframe in a for loop ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `pd.concat` if I could

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'])

  df1 df2 df3
0   a   e   i
1   b   f   j
2   c   g   k
3   d   h   l
```

You could also use `pd.concat` with a dictionary

```
pd.concat({'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'df3': df3}, axis=1)

  df1 df2 df3
0   a   e   i
1   b   f   j
2   c   g   k
3   d   h   l
```

---

But if you must use a loop

```
df_agg = None

for name, df in zip(['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], [df1, df2, df3]):
    if df_agg is None:
        df_agg = df.to_frame(name)
    else:
        df_agg[name] = df

df_agg

  df1 df2 df3
0   a   e   i
1   b   f   j
2   c   g   k
3   d   h   l
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. but I must use a loop. because Actually, I have to deal with a series of large databases. I don't understand well how to use concat in loop.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can save a lot of time.  But is there any way to use Pandas' append feature? I can not intuitively understand the above code because I am not familiar with some of basic function like zip().

Comment: @ukebida please get familiar with `zip`!  It's is a huge piece of python that should not be overlooked.  I use it because I need a mechanism for providing a name for the column along with the column that is to be added.  Run this to see what `zip` does `list(zip(['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], [df1, df2, df3]))`.  In regards to `append`.  I believe that append is the wrong choice.  I could force an answer that uses `append` but it would be very inefficient.  `append` adds rows when you are specifically adding columns.  The option to use would be `pd.concat` but...

Comment: `pd.concat` would require rewriting the dataframe from scratch each time and overwriting the original dataframe.  Again, inefficient.  What I proposed, adds a single column each loop.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. I got it. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I do not exactly want answers, but can I ask you a question? If I want to load Series from database, not like predefined, do I have to make variables using loop and make a list and using zip ?

Comment: I am trying to load Series from database, and I tried to apply it to that case. but I can not imagine process.