# There are three problems(Load database, loop, and append series)

Tags: pandas

Unlike when I started, I found this problem to be a more difficult problem than I thought.

I want to refer to a particular column content from the SQLite database, make it into a Series, and then combine it into a single data frame.

I have tried like this but faild:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/Kun/Documents/Dashin/data.db") #my sqldb
tmplist = ['A003060','A003070'] #db contains that table,I decided to call 
                                   #only two for practice.

for i in tmplist:
    tmpSeries =pd.Series([]) 
    listSeries = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM %s " %(i), con , index_col = 
    None)['Close'].head(5)
    tmpSeries2 = tmpSeries.append(listSeries)

    print(tmpSeries2)
```

that code result show only dummy thing like this:

```
0    7150.0
1    6770.0
2    7450.0
3    7240.0
4    6710.0
dtype: float64
0    14950.0
1    15500.0
2    15000.0
3    14800.0
4    14500.0
```

What I want to do is like this:

```
   A003060    A003070
0    7150.0   14950.0
1    6770.0   15500.0
2    7450.0   15000.0
3    7240.0   14800.0
4    6710.0   14500.0
```

I had a similar question ahead and got a answer. But The last question is 
using predefined variables. But I must use  loop because I have to deal with a series of large databases. I have already tried another effort using dataframe.append, transpose(). But I failed.

I would appreciate some small hints. Thank you.

[To append pandas series using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272854/to-append-pandas-series-using-for-loop/45272875?noredirect=1#comment77509374_45272875)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create `list`, then append data and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = []
for i in tmplist:
    tmpSeries =pd.Series([]) 
    listSeries = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM %s " %(i) con,index_col = None)['Close'].head(5)
    dfs.append(listSeries)

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=tmplist)
print(df)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for your help. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day too!